# Compare a 2d array to an array Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an 2D array:

```
2d_arr = [[a,b,c,d],[a,b],[c,d],[a,f]]
```

And another array:

```
arr = [a,w,b,x]
```

I want to compare every element in the 2D array (2d_arr) with the array (arr) and get the output as a new 2D array like this: (if the 2D array elements match the array put 1 else 0)

```
[a,w,b,x]
[1,0,1,0]
[1,0,1,0]
[0,0,0,0]
[1,0,0,0]
```

I have tried the follow:

```
for i in range(len(2d_arr)):
   for j in range(len(2d_arr[i])):
      if 2d_arr[i][j] == arr[i]
         .....
```

I know the arr[i] from the last line is wrong but how would i iterate??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
arr_2d = [['a','b','c','d'],['a','b'],['c','d'],['a','f']]
arr = ['a','w','b','x']

[[int(x in a) for x in arr] for a in arr_2d]

[[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```